# A class system for Roguelike

Tags: java, roguelike

What would be a good way to implement a race system similar to [Roguelike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) in Java.

I have been thinking about making each creature a subclass of it's race but I'm not sure this is a good way to do things.

Comment: Please read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq your question is not a good fit for stack overflow. Maybe one of the sister sites but not this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I implement body parts in a Java roguelike game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049510/how-could-i-implement-body-parts-in-a-java-roguelike-game)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly don't want a subclass relationship. I would use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) rather than [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29).

In particular, I would make a class `Race`

```
public class Race {

    public String name;

    public Race(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and ensure that each creature has a `Race` field.